# What is a sql anonymous object and how would i use it? It came up in an online tutorial i'm following

Tags: c#

What is a sql anonymous object and how would i use it?
It came up in an online tutorial i'm following.

Sample code:

```cs
Sql = "select Id from dbo.contacts where FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName;";
int contactId = DB.LoadData<IdLookupModel, dynamic>(Sql, new
    {
        contact.BasicInfo.FirstName,
        contact.BasicInfo.LastName
    },
    _ConnectionString).First().id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous object is not part of sql but of your dotnet code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types for more details.

In general you can say that you may create any object without a corresponding class. In your example this is the anonymous object:

```cs
new {
    contact.BasicInfo.FirstName,
    contact.BasicInfo.LastName
}
```

It is passed as the parameters to you sql queries and then mapped to `@FirstName` and `@LastName`. The names are taken from the property names. You can also set your own names:

```cs
new {
    GivenName = contact.BasicInfo.FirstName,
    FamilyName = contact.BasicInfo.LastName
}
```

You can than access the parameters via `@GivenName` and `@FamilyName`.